# Typescript generics: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'

Tags: typescript

Here is some typescript code:

```
class ClassA<T extends BlueItem = BlueItem> {

    protected _list: Array<T>;

    get list(): Array<T> {
        return this._list;
    }
}

class ClassB<T extends GreenItem = GreenItem> extends ClassA<T> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._list.push(new GreenItem());
    }
}

class BlueItem {
    protected blueItemProperty: number;
}


class GreenItem extends BlueItem {
    protected greenItemProperty: number;
}
```

Compiler says "Argument of type 'GreenItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'. What would be a correct approach to solve this?

Comment: There's some hole in design - you're trying to push `GreenItem` to list that potentially of type `RedItem[]` where  `RedItem` derives from `GreenItem`

Comment: ClassB is generic. It contains an array of T, which can be any type, as long as this type extends GreenItem. So T could be, for example, LighGreenItem. And the array should thus only contain elements of type LighGreenItem. But you're trying to push a GreenItem inside. A GreenItem is not  LighGreenItem.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem, but is there a way of solving this without overriding _list and get list() in ClassB and all other classes which extends ClassA with type set to GreenItem/SomeOtherItem?

Comment: Why `ClassB` is generic? Just define it as `class ClassB extends ClassA<GreenItem>`

Comment: What if I want ClassC which extends ClassB and _list should be of RedItem type?

Comment: You'll need to provide constructor function for derived item (generic type info is not available at runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't generate the correct types (T) inside your class, because you don't know what T is. Since you don't want to pass a factory function into your class, the next best solution would be to use union types and allow both types, like this:

```
class ClassA<T = BlueItem> {

   protected _list:Array<T | BlueItem>;

   get list(): Array<T | BlueItem> {
    return this._list;
   }
}

class ClassB<T = GreenItem> extends ClassA<T | GreenItem> {
}

class ClassC extends ClassB<RedItem> {
}
```

However, here you'd need to check the items from the list to be the right type.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve the problem would be to make constructor of the list items also "generic":

```
class ClassB<T extends GreenItem = GreenItem> extends ClassA<T>
{
  constructor(listItemCtor: {new(): T})
  {
    super();

    const t = new listItemCtor();

    this._list.push(t);
  }
}
```

Its not universal solution - but if applicable - it will help.

As an option you can also drop generics altogether in the base class:

```
class ClassA
{
    protected _list: Array<any>;
}

class ClassB<T extends GreenItem = GreenItem> extends ClassA
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();

    this._list.push(new GreenItem());
  }

  get list(): Array<T>
  {
    return this._list;
  }
}
```

You will not loose much as you still have type checking on public properties of ClassB. And `_list` is internal.

Comment: I want end-user not to worry about the types, so that he could simply do new ClassB(). When default generics were introduced, I expected that this will be possible. Let's say I have 10 different lists, with this approach user will break his neck passing all the parameters.

Comment: Then the option that is left - is to drop generics from the base class. See my update.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve it - within ClassA I want list to be of BlueItem[] type. And, if I have ClassC which extends ClassB, I will face this problem again.

Comment: I think you are a bit abusing the generics. If you have such nested class hierarchy you should be looking into creating corresponding classes using mostly inheritance instead, as generics will not be of much help here.

Comment: Most likely you are right, the thing I don't like is that I will have to repeat a lot of getters/setters in each class just to have a correct type. This adds a lot of unnecessary code to compiled JavaScript.

Comment: I posted additional question about telling TS compiler to skip some of the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075308/tell-typescript-compiler-not-to-compile-some-of-the-code

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `GreenItem` to `T`.

```
class ClassB<T extends GreenItem = GreenItem> extends ClassA<T> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._list.push(<T>new GreenItem());
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't result error, but I would say it's a very wrong approach.

Comment: Why wrong? You can't cast to `T` if the class is not a `T`.

Comment: Well, you could do <T>new BlueItem() and it won't show error.

Comment: Yes. It is a `BlueItem` list. It seems all right to me.