# Tell typescript compiler not to compile some of the code

Tags: typescript

Following this question about Generics: [Typescript generics: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068834/typescript-generics-argument-of-type-x-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type/) :

`get list()` and `protected _list` in the following code are added to each class just to have a proper type. However, when compiled to JavaScript these methods and class property are identical in all three classes. Is there a way to tell Typescript compiler to skip duplicates and leave one getter/class property in ClassA only?

```
class ClassA {

       protected _list:Array<BlueItem>;

       get list(): Array<BlueItem> {
        return this._list;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

       protected _list:Array<GreenItem>;

       get list(): Array<GreenItem> {
        return this._list;
    }
}

class ClassC extends ClassB {

       protected _list:Array<RedItem>;

       get list(): Array<RedItem> {
        return this._list;
    }
}

class BlueItem {

}

class GreenItem extends BlueItem {

}

class RedItem extends BlueItem {

}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it in typescript using

```
class ClassA<T = BlueItem> {

   protected _list:Array<T | BlueItem>;

   get list(): Array<T | BlueItem> {
    return this._list;
   }
}

class ClassB<T = GreenItem> extends ClassA<T | GreenItem> {
}

class ClassC extends ClassB<RedItem> {
}
```

This is not 100% equivalent, you could change it further by restricting the generic type to need to extend BlueItem or GreenItem, ...

Comment: The link in the top of this question explains why this approach is not suitable.

Comment: @zeroin I've updated my example, if you want to be able to set the value within each class, without passing a constructor inside, you need to be aware that when you'll read the data it might be `T` **or** the default generic used by the base class. Specifying that on the array / in the genrics you're passing down, is the only way to allow it in typescript

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting suggestion - if you'd post it to the original question, It would be the best answer.